# Euler characteristic of affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Sorry for the trivial question.. but what is the (topological) Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Also, is there a genus-degree formula for affine curves similar to $g={d-1\choose 2}$ for smooth projective curves, so that $\chi=2-2g$ can be determined?

Comment: You mean complex affine space?

Comment: In that case, it is somewhat strange that one may know what the topological Euler characteristic is and, at the same time, not know what the homology of a contractible space like $\mathbb C^n$ is!

Comment: By $\mathbb{A}^n$, I mean affine space over any algebraically closed field. $\mathbb{C}^n$ is contractible to a point so the homology is trivial.. I guess $\chi=1$, but I wanted to make sure..

Comment: But over an albutrary algebraically closed field, it is not quite clear what you mean by *topological* Euler characteristc. With its Zariski topology either the maximal spectrum or the whole prime spectrum has a very weird topology...

Comment: If you mean the Euler characteristic defined as $\chi(X)=\sum_i h^i(X, \mathcal O_X)$, then $\chi(X)$ of an affine space is infinite unless $X$ is zero-dimensional.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer: that is the holomorphic Euler characteristic, not the topological Euler characteristic.

Comment: @Mariano: what's the problem of defining the Euler characteristic through the sheaf cohomology of constant sheaf for arbitrary variety with its Zariski topology? I have no idea what the answer is but that makes the question all the more interesting.

Comment: -1 since the OP hasn't clarified the notion of "topological Euler characteristic" (applied to a variety).

Comment: @FredrikMeyer, why do you say that sum is infinite?